# Django value, annotate issue?

Tags: python, django

This is very simple, but I don't know exactly..

This is Some tables (Two)

1. Football_game Table : id, game_name, score_user_id(FK), score, date
2. User Table :id, name, email

I need a sum of score by user in spacific date include all information(Football_game)

This is my code

```
football_list = Football_game.objects.filter(date='2017-04-18')
football_data = football_list.values(score_user_id).annotate(sumOfScore=Sum('score'))

game_lists = [entry for entry in football_data]
for game_list in game_lists
   blah blah..
```

There is some problems.
I need more information for the football game (date, game_name, etc..)

How can I get this from object?

Comment: I am not sure even this would work.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that. For example

```
Userid game score
1      g1   10
1      g2   10
2      g1   5
```

So from above, `GROUP BY` `Userid` and `score` will be like

```
1 -> 20  
2 -> 5
```

So from `1->20` row, it contains both `g1` and `g2`.So there is no specification about which game. That is why, you cannot get other columns when using annotations `Sum` from same table.